# change localization in C# on Windows Universal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I follow this training for making resource language file for My Universal Windows 8.1 application:
[How to use Multilingual App Toolkit in Universal Apps](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/how-to-use-multilingual-app-toolkit-in-universal-apps)

Then I search a little for create a button to change language app without changing system region and language. I found this code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

I want to add a button in setting page then I change my app language and restart app for show that. This code doesn't work for me. I want to do this in windows universal 8.1.
Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride`.
See [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx)

Comment: I need to use it before initialize to update page value. Is there any way to that after page loaded completely?